# Scrolling webpage issue in Brave(chromium browsers)

Tags: browser, brave

I have had this issue for a long time and have tried extensions too but just can't get the original feel of scrolling in chromium browsers. Currently on Ubuntu 22.04.1, does anyone have any solution?